# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't recognize my dual jack headset's microphone

Tags: microphone

Alright, I have an issue that seems to be prominent with Ubuntu-based operating systems. When I plug in my headset, which comes with two jacks (one for the microphone and the other for the headphones), regardless of which one I connect it will not input audio from the headset's microphone.

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04.

The headphones jack does work. The microphone jack does not.

My laptop only has one jack.

Do I need to try buying an adapter that can connect those two jacks into a USB? Do I need to buy a different microphone?

Here is the results of $inxi -Fxz

```
enter code here
           base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 

Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: GL553VD v: 1.0 serial: <filter>
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: GL553VD v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
           UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: GL553VD.306 date: 01/02/2018

Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 38.7 Wh condition: 41.2/48.2 Wh (85%)
           model: Simplo SDI ICR18650 status: Discharging 

CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-7700HQ bits: 64 type: MT MCP
           arch: Kaby Lake rev: 9 L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 44928 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/3800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
           3: 801 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 

Graphics:  Device-1: Intel vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] vendor: ASUSTeK 
           driver: nvidia v: 390.77 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
           unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.77 
           direct render: Yes 

Audio:     Device-1: Intel CM238 HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel
           v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-45-generic

Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless 7265 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: e000 
           bus ID: 02:00.0 
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
           vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
           IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter> 

Drives:    Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 55.67 GiB (6.0%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS721010A9E630 
           size: 931.51 GiB 

Partition: ID-1: / size: 915.89 GiB used: 55.67 GiB (6.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 

Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 39 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 

Info:      Processes: 259 Uptime: 1h 46m Memory: 7.67 GiB used: 1.96 GiB (25.5%) 
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.3.0 Shell: bash v: 4.4.19 
           inxi: 3.0.27
```